# Recoding race variable with 9 categories to dummy

Tags: r, missing-data, na, categorical-data, dummy-data

Allow me to preface this by saying that I am new to R. I cleaned some income and rent variables and now I am trying to recode my race variable from 9 categories to 2. The original variable is coded as follows:

1=White 2=Black 3=Native 4=Asian 5=A 6=B 7=C 8=D 9=E. I'm basically trying to eliminate all other races and only keep White and Black as a dummy variable, where White=0 and Black=1. Here's the code:

```
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)
df<-read.dta("acs2010.dta")
View(df)
attach(df)
summary(df)

inctot[inctot==9999999]<-NA
inctot[inctot<=0]<-NA
summary(inctot)
incomesq<-(inctot)^2

rent[rent==0]<-NA
summary(rent)

levels(race)[1]<-"White"
levels(race)[2]<-"Black"
levels(race)[3:9]<-NA
levels(race)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=race))+geom_bar()
view(df)
```

Manipulating the levels leaves me with "White" and "Black" but when I plot it, it shows the NA's as well. I'm not sure how to get rid of NA's in factor variables. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title of this question: it seems to really be about omitting missing data from the plot, rather than about recoding a factor as a dummy variable.  Better title will be more helpful to future readers.

Comment: Sorry about making it sound like i was a plotting issue. I'm actually struggling with creating a dummy variable from a categorical variable and the plot made me aware of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach in the question to recoding the `race` factor looks fine.

It seems that the real problem here was omitting the `NA`s from the plot.  Just subset the data frame:

`ggplot(data =`**`df[!is.na(df$race),]`**`, aes(x=race)) + geom_bar()`

Further reading:

- [using `[]` to subset data](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Getting_a_subset_of_a_data_structure/)
- [using `is.na`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Working_with_NULL_NA_and_NaN/#removing-bad-values-from-a-vector)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the plot worked just fine! I am familiar with some other statistical packages that have easy recoding procedures such as Stata. Is this the easiest way to create dummy variables in R? I know that having a factor variable is advantageous and requires no extra work when running a regression models, but for some reason creating dummies seems like lots of work in R.

Comment: I don't have tons of experience with it, but from the Cookbook-R page on [recoding data](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Recoding_data/), it looks fairly reasonable...